# JIRA general technical limits

Tags: numbers, jira

I am currently looking for JIRA technical limitations (like number of users, groups, roles, projects, issue types, number of screens, of fields, ...)
Do you know where I could find this sort of informations ? Atlassian site ? another one ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent document of scaling JIRA, in which it lists down the numbers and statistics on how much a JIRA instance can go.

Basically, what this document presents the many factors that can impact JIRA's performance. Many users tend to believe that projects, issues and users are the main causes of performance degradation. However, there are other factors such as:

- permission schemes (the more schemes you have, the more it's going to take JIRA to analyse the permission actions for a user).
- workflow steps (if a workflow contains a lot of steps, it would require some time for JIRA to assess the next status in a transition, and the possible transitions for a status).
- plugins (more plugins, more memory consumption; and more calculations on top of the two mentioned above).

Let's not forget the users concurrency as well!

You can review more of this in this document: [Scaling JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/Scaling+JIRA).